# The usage of 議論の余地

Tags: phrases

I can't figure out if the phrase 議論の余地 is used to convey the meaning of "there is no room for arguing about that" or what else it conveys. Also, is it weird to use it? I couldn't find many resources about it, so I guess it is not used often.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually said: 議論の余地がある meaning there is room for discussion, ie. something can be argued or is debatable.

"There is no room for arguing that" -> 議論の余地がない

Plenty of examples [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%AD%B0%E8%AB%96%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%99%E5%9C%B0%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B)

It is used when it makes sense to use it, maybe in more formalish situations.